# Doctrine connection failed during getting ORM Service Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I cannot seem to connect the doctrine entity manager using my configurations. The username and password are correctr.

Here is my doctrine configuratuion inside `config/autoload/global.php`

```
'doctrine' => [
    'connection' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
            'params' => [
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'user'     => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'dbname'   => 'callisto',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

I integrated the `DoctrineORM` and `Doctrine` modules from zend framework.

My problem is that when I write this command inside `the onBootstrap method of Application/src/Module.php:`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{   
    $doctrineOrm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array) #1 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(41): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array) #2 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'username', 'password', Array) #3 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() #4 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() #5 /var/www/html/pp/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib in /var/www/html/pp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 754
```

Not sure what the problem is, maybe im missing a configuration? Here's my `Application module config (module.config.php)`:

```
    'doctrine' => [
            'driver' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                            'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                            'cache' => 'array',
                            'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity']
                    ],
                    'orm_default' => [
                            'drivers' => [
                                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) means that you dont have the correct user and password for your database.

Comment: Nope the credentials are correct which is my issue.

Comment: I added the issue to the question

Comment: If you have a config/autoload/local.php file, this can be overwriting the previous configuration